# Liberty InstantOn with spring-boot-starter-security throws exception

Tags: spring-boot, open-liberty, spring-boot-security

I found an article about Liberty InstantOn feature, and that you can combine this with spring boot https://openliberty.io/blog/2023/09/26/spring-boot-3-instant-on.html. If I add `spring-boot-starter-security`  the applications starts with an exception (during check pointing and application startup). I made a reproducer, based on the example code of the blog post https://github.com/TetrisIQ/LibertyInstantOnSpringBoot/. The app was build with Java 17

```java
openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This is the stack trace I got:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionServicePostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor]: Factory method 'conversionServicePostProcessor' threw exception with message: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyFactory not available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:202) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:15) ~[thin-guide-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.springboot.internal.SpringBootRuntimeContainer.lambda$invokeSpringMain$6(SpringBootRuntimeContainer.java:139) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:280) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:857) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor]: Factory method 'conversionServicePostProcessor' threw exception with message: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyFactory not available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyFactory not available
        at org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters.rsaFactory(RsaKeyConverters.java:148) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters.x509(RsaKeyConverters.java:114) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.springframework.security.config.crypto.RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.<init>(RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.conversionServicePostProcessor(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:185) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyFactory not available
        at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.<init>(KeyFactory.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyFactory.java:183) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters.rsaFactory(RsaKeyConverters.java:145) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

I tryed diffrent Java versions, and runs the container with root privalages.

Comment: *RSA KeyFactory not available*

Comment: I know @Jens, but when I build this normally (mvn spring-boot:run) it works. So I guess RSA KeyFactory is not available inside the docker.

Comment: Which jdk do you use at build time and which at runtime?

Comment: Build time, the one above. Run time this one 
`openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition 17.0.9.0 (build 17.0.9+9)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM 17.0.9.0 (build openj9-0.41.0, JRE 17 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20231017_614 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
`

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I will wait for next Liberty release, and test than with Java21

Comment: The Java 21 Semeru release and Liberty Java 21 images are now available to fix this.  Try out the latest beta image icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty:beta (see https://openliberty.io/blog/2024/02/05/Java21-Images.html).  Also note that you can enable the CRaC support with the beta: https://openliberty.io/blog/2023/09/26/spring-boot-3-instant-on.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of a limitation in Semeru Java support for checkpoint/restore.  This has been fixed in the Java 21 release of Semeru with https://github.com/ibmruntimes/openj9-openjdk-jdk/pull/685

I expect it will also be fixed for earlier releases of Semeru Java (11 and 17) in their next releases.  The upcoming Liberty (24.0.0.1) should soon have container images available that use Semeru Java 21 with this fixed.